# Registry Query for batch script

Tags: batch, batch-file, script

I am trying to create a batch script, (only specifically batch script), to check if the latest Microsoft Office version is installed to my computer. If it detects the latest version, it will output hello, else it will output heyo.  However, the if else statement doesn't seem to be working as I kept receiving the echo "heyo" even when the correct version of Office is installed.

What I tried:

```bath
@echo off

for /f "skip=1 tokens=3 delims= " %%a in ('
      reg query "HKEY_LOCALMACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\ClickToRun\Configuration" /v VersionToReport
    ') do set "VersionToReport=%%~a"

IF "%VersionToReport%" EQU "16.0.10396.20023" (
       echo hello
     ) else (
       echo heyo
     )
```

Comment: `EQU` is for numbers. Use `==` for strings. See [If - Conditionally perform command - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)

Comment: `DO` should be on the same line as `FOR`

Comment: The results are still the same when == is used and placing DO in the same line as FOR

Comment: Tested the batch file and it works as expected on my system ... are you sure the version is correct?

Comment: @DavidPostill If the above method doesn't work, is there another way of achieving this? I am trying to check if the reg string matches "16.0.10396.20023", it will echo hello. If it doesn't reflect that version number or if the registry doesn't even exists, it will echo heyo. Thanks!

Comment: @GChuf Yep the version is correct. It help reflecting the else statement although the version is correct. I tested on different registries as well. Does yours echo the if statement?

Comment: Yes, it echoes "hello".
Maybe you should lose the quotes? Try this:
`%VersionToReport%  == 16.0.10396.20023`

Comment: Hi All, Thank you for your time. My colleague manage to get it works. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Unless you really need to store the current version number in a variable, then the easiest approach would be to execute the command (`reg query`) and search for the string you want (`16.0.10396.20023`) in the output.

You can then use the value of `%errorlevel%` to determine if it was found or not, like so:

```
reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\ClickToRun\Configuration" /v VersionToReport | findstr "16.0.10396.20023"
if %errorlevel% equ 0 (
    echo Version is okay
) else (
    echo Version is not okay
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```bath
@echo off

2>nul reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\ClickToRun\Configuration" /v VersionToReport | find "16.0.10396.20023" >nul && echo\hello || echo\heyo
```

- Or...

```bath
@echo off

set "_Hkey="HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\ClickToRun\Configuration" /v VersionToReport
2>nul reg.exe query %_Hkey% | find "16.0.10396.20023" >nul && echo\hello || echo\heyo
```

---

You can use operators:

```bath
command && ( run if return 0)
command || ( run if return non 0)

command && echo\is zOk || echo\isn't ok
```

---

```bath
@echo off

for /f "skip=1 tokens=3 delims= " %%a in (
   '2^>nul reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\ClickToRun\Configuration" /v VersionToReport'
    )do set "VersionToReport=%%~a" && if "%%~a" == "16.0.10396.20023" (echo\hello)else echo\heyo

if defined VersionToReport (
     echo; Version: %VersionToReport%)else echo\Wrong version!
```

---

## Some further reading:

- **[`Find /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/find.html)**
- **[Conditional Execution](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)**

  - **[`||`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html) and [`&&`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)**
- **[Commands Redirection](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)**

  - **`|`**, **`<`**, **`>`**, **`2>`**, **`2>&1`**, etc.